# Access canvas elements of Kivy widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I've drawn a widget background using a `RoundedRectangle` in a kv file. Now I want to create a different widget and the only difference from this one is the background color. The properties approach (suggested by @inclement) gives me a strange error. For some reason, the property works when I use it in a different place (`cursor_color`, for example) so I'd expect it to work here. So, the new question is why isn't that property getting recognized?

```
<Message>:
    BoxLayout:
        colour_property: 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 1
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: root.pos
                size: self.size
            Color:
                rgba: self.colour_property
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: root.x + 1, root.y + 1
                size: self.width - 2, self.height - 2

        TextInput:
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size
```

And the Python code:

```
class Message(Widget):
    colour_property = ListProperty([0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 1])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.colour_property = ListProperty([0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 1])
        super(Message, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

The error occurs when parsing the `rgba: self.colour_property` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a property to transfer the value:

```
BoxLayout:
    colour_property: 1, 1, 1, 1
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: root.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: self.colour_property
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: root.x + 1, root.y + 1
            size: self.width - 2, self.height - 2

    TextInput:
        pos: root.pos
        size: root.size
```

You might also want/need to declare the property in your python code (i.e. make a class with the property and make a rule for it instead).

Comment: For some reason it does not recognize that property. I've defined it in the `__init__`, outside, in the kv as you've shown and it still gives me a parsing error. Any ideas on what may be wrong here? I've edited the post to show the code

Comment: The kv you've posted now is for a BoxLayout, did you mean to make that a Message?

Comment: I've just omitted the part of the Message reference, but here it is

Comment: 1) Don't set self.colour_property to a ListProperty in your `__init__`, setting it at class level is enough. 2) Your canvas rule references self.colour_property but you should use root.colour_property to refer to the top level Message.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried changing many things, including the changes you've mentioned. Still getting a parsing error.

Comment: Never mind, I might have messed something up when I tried that earlier because now I've got it to work :)